# JSTL <c:if> comparing 2 model objects

Tags: spring, jsp, jstl

Hello im trying to mark as selected or not a select html box i want to compare each option with another string i add to my model in order to determine which is the selected option, the problem is i cant handle it to make it work, it keeps saying equal symbol expected

Here is my code:

```
                <select name="version" onchange="document.forms['versionForm'].submit();">
                    <c:forEach var="conf" items="${hconfs}" varStatus="status">
                    <c:if test="${conf == 'versionUsed'}">
                        <option value="${conf}"><fmt:formatDate value="${conf}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a" selected/></option>
                    </c:if> 
                    <c:if test="${conf != 'versionUsed'}">
                        <option value="${conf}"><fmt:formatDate value="${conf}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"/></option>
                    </c:if>                         
                    </c:forEach>
                </select>
```

This is the error i get

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/view/configuracion.jsp(86,104) equal symbol expected
```

Comment: Don't paraphrase the error message. Copy and paste it.

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/view/configuracion.jsp(86,104) equal symbol expected

Comment: And which line is line 86? Which column is column 104?

Comment: This one: <option value="${conf}"><fmt:formatDate value="${conf}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a" selected/></option>

Comment: I already find the error the problem was the selected attribute, should be wrritten in this way: <option value="${confi}" selected="selected" ><fmt:formatDate value="${confi}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a" /></option>

Comment: The html `selected` needs to be outside the `<fmt>` tag.

Comment: @jlars62: you should post that as an answer. I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: @JBNizet Your problem solving instructions were the real answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The html `selected` needs to be outside the `<fmt>` tag and part of the `option` tag.

So you need to change this line:

```
<option value="${conf}"><fmt:formatDate value="${conf}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a" selected/></option>
```

to:

```
<option value="${conf}" selected><fmt:formatDate value="${conf}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a" /></option>
                        ^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the selected attribute, i placed it wrong, it should be written this way:

```
<option value="${confi}" selected="selected" ><fmt:formatDate value="${confi}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a" /></option>
```